# How to implement AND clause in Rails Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following query:

```
select source_names.id as source_id, source_names.name as source_name, source_types.id as source_type_id,source_types.name type_name,event_sources.id
  from source_names
    left join source_types
    on source_type_id = source_types.id
   left join event_sources
   on source_names.id = event_sources.source_id and event_id = 1


result = SourceName.joins('
                                LEFT JOIN source_types ON source_type_id = source_types.id
                                LEFT JOIN event_sources ON source_names.id = event_sources.source_id
                              ').where('event_id =?',event_id).select('source_names.id as source_id, source_names.name as source_name, source_types.id as source_type_id,source_types.name type_name,event_sources.id').all
```

yields:

```
select source_names.id as source_id, source_names.name as source_name, source_types.id as source_type_id,source_types.name type_name,event_sources.id
      from source_names
        left join source_types
        on source_type_id = source_types.id
       left join event_sources
       on source_names.id = event_sources.source_id WHERE event_id = 1
```

But I want `and event_id = 1`

How'd I accomplish that?

Comment: @vee Can you elaborate what are you saying?

Comment: Example: `SourceName.joins('LEFT JOIN event_sources ON source_names.id = event_sources.source_id AND event_sources.event_id = 1')...`.

Comment: @vee It does work but a couple of questions,1)How do I pass parameterized value of event_id? 2) Is it `rails way` to tackle this issue?

Comment: That is indeed an interesting question to me, I've not tried parameterized joins.  Please feel free to post the results of your attempts.

Comment: @vee Seems I have no choice other than doing this: `LEFT JOIN event_sources ON source_names.id = event_sources.source_id AND event_id = '+event_id.to_s+'` I wanted a SQL Injection safe way for a paramterized query or I say, prepared statement

Comment: @vee make your comment as an ANS and I will accept it

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a WHERE, don't use `.where`

Just add it to your joins:

```
SourceName.joins('
  LEFT JOIN source_types ON source_type_id = source_types.id
  LEFT JOIN event_sources ON source_names.id = event_sources.source_id and event_sources.event_id = 1')
```